# PHP 5.1.6 - Site showing Object # instead of content in many places

Tags: php, linux, centos

I'm trying to set up a mirror of a site on another server and as far as a I can see, the spec matches (both running php 5.1.6 on CentOS 5). However, in a number of places on the mirror site, I am getting an "Object #.." displaying instead of content - I realise this is to do with toString(). I had this problem before when moving a site from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.1.6, but i'm not sure why it would be happening on one 5.1.6 install and not another - any one have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Prior to 5.2, `__toString` (note: it's not `toString`) [is only called when directly combined with echo or print](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring). If that can't explain your problem, please post the code.

Comment: The issue is why I'm getting different behaviour on two servers, both running php 5.1.6 and both configured the same as far as I can see. I set up a clone of the site and server so I can do development work before pushing to live, but this is a bit of a spanner in the works

Answer (score 0):

Is short tag enabled in the php.ini?

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Answer (score 0):

From PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) ...

"It is worth noting that before PHP 5.2.0 the __toString() method was only called when it was directly combined with echo() or print(). Since PHP 5.2.0, it is called in any string context (e.g. in printf() with %s modifier) but not in other types contexts (e.g. with %d modifier)."

Can you check your code to see if the object is being rendered with echo or print?  If you are using printf then perhaps you are mistaken about the other server running php 5.1.6.